Two-Photon Interference But Different Global Phases
If two identical photons enter a beam splitter at the same time, they will always exit the beam splitter togheter (the Hong–Ou–Mandel effect), however small changes in timing can make them leave by different ports. Also, different polarizations also make them be able to leave by different ports.
My question is, if one of them has a global phase which is not the same as the other photon, will it change the probabilities of leaving togheter or alone?

No, it will have no difference.
In the case considered, the input state is $|1\rangle\otimes |1\rangle$. Since the state is separable, it is possible to talk about multiplying each of them by a global phase, to yield
$$(e^{i\phi}|1\rangle)\otimes (e^{i\theta}|1\rangle)=e^{i(\phi+\theta)}(|1\rangle\otimes |1\rangle),$$ where I added parentheses for clarity. Since $\theta+\phi$ is a global phase acting on the entire state, it has no effect on any physics.
